# Unsure how to send image to backend using express file upload,

Tags: javascript

someone please help im trying to submit details together with image to databasei need help in figuring this whole thing out

```
<form id="register-form">
        <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*">
        </div> -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="file-upload">
                <div class="image-upload-wrap">
                    <input name = 'sampleFile' enctype = "multipart/form-data" class="file-upload-input" type='file' id="profilepic" onchange="readImage(this)"
                        accept="image/*" />
                    <div class="drag-text">
                        <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="file-upload-content d-none">
                    <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" id="imgPreview" />
                    <div class="image-title-wrap">
                        <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image">Remove <span
                                class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="release">Release:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="release" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lang">Language_id:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lang" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rental_duration">Rental Duration:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rental_duration" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rental_rate">Rental rate:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rental_rate" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="length">Length:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="replacement_cost">Replacement Cost:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="replacement_cost" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rating" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="special_features">Special Features:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="special_features" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category_id">Category ID:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_id" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="actors">Actors:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="actors" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="store_id">Store_id:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="store_id" required>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary ml-5">Reset</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-5" id="Logout">Log Out</button>
        <!-- <input type="reset" value="Reset">   -->
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8081";
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const loggedInUserID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("loggedInUserID"));
    console.log(token, loggedInUserID)

  //  document.getElementById("addImage").addEventListener("change", function () {
  //      readImage(this);
    //});
 //   document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
   //     var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    //});

    function readImage(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var imgPreview = document.getElementById("imgPreview");
                imgPreview.src = e.target.result;
                document.getElementById("imgPreview").style.display = "block";
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


    if (token === null || isNaN(loggedInUserID)) {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/home";
    } else {
        $("#register-form").submit((event) => {
            // prevent page reload
            event.preventDefault();
            const pic = $("#profilepic").val()
            const title = $("#title").val();
            const description = $("#description").val();
            const release = $("#release").val();
            const lang = $("#lang").val();
            const rental_duration = $("#rental_duration").val();
            const rental_rate = $("#rental_rate").val();
            const length = $("#length").val();
            const replacement_cost = $("#replacement_cost").val();
            const rating = $("#rating").val();
            const feature = $("#special_features").val();
            const category_id = $("#category_id").val();
            const actors = $("#actors").val();
            const store_id = $("#store_id").val();

            const requestBody = {
                image: pic,
                title: title,
                description: description,
                release_year: release,
                language_id: lang,
                rental_duration: rental_duration,
                rental_rate: rental_rate,
                length: length,
                replacement_cost: replacement_cost,
                rating: rating,
                special_features: feature,
                category_id: category_id,
                actors: actors,
                store_id: store_id
            };
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", pic);
            formData.append("title", title);
            formData.append("description", description);
            formData.append("release_year", release);
            formData.append("language_id", lang);
            formData.append("rental_duration", rental_duration);
            formData.append("rental_rate", rental_rate);
            formData.append("length", length);
            formData.append("replacement_cost", replacement_cost);
            formData.append("rating", rating);
            formData.append("special_features", feature);
            formData.append("category_id", category_id);
            formData.append("actors", actors);
            formData.append("store_id", store_id);

            let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            console.log(requestBody);
            axios.post(`${baseUrl}/film`, formData, { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + token } })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(formData)
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/home";
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    if (error.response.status === 400) {
                        alert("Validation failed");
                    } else {
                        alert("Something unexpected went wrong.");
                    }
                });
        });



        
        $("#Logout").click(function () {
            window.localStorage.clear();
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            localStorage.removeItem("loggedInUserID");
            window.location.assign("http://localhost:3001/home");
        });
    }
    
</script>


    const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileUpload());
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
    }
      
        let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
      
        // Use the mv() method to place the file in a upload directory
        sampleFile.mv("./upload/" + sampleFile.name, (err) => {
          if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
          res.send("File uploaded!");
        });
      });
```

my html form code and app.js code i just cannot send image to database idk why, i  try usin express file upload but the code just cannot insert it in. Someone, please help i have 48 hours left before my deadline please!!!!!!  this is my first time doing this , someone guide me